MUI Date Picker does not render value
I am able to control the state of the MUI date picker to view and set the value on the screen but it does not show when I try to view it in the developer tool console and also when I try to print it the console.
This is my code below:
import React, {useContext} from "react";
import {Button, TextField, FormControl, InputLabel, 
    MenuItem, Select, Box} from '@mui/material'
import { multiStepContext } from "../StepContext";
import {LocalizationProvider} from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import {AdapterDayjs} from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import {DatePicker} from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker"

export default function SecondStep(){
    const {setStep, userData , setUserData} = useContext(multiStepContext);
        
          return (
        <div className="container"> 
        <div className="container-input"> 
        <h3 style={{color: "red", position: "relative" }}>Student Information </h3>  
    <div>
    <Box style={{  minWidth: 200 }} > 
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DatePicker
   
          label="Date of Birth"
          onChange={( newValue)=> setUserData ({...userData, "dateofbirth": newValue})}
          renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} />}
          value={ userData["dateofbirth"]}
         
          >
         </DatePicker>
          </LocalizationProvider>
          </Box>
          </div> 

I want to be able to get hold of the value when I check at the developer tool console, pls can someone help with the code to achieve this?

How did you declare multiStepContext and what is it’s relationship with SecondStep’s Parent?

"I try to view it in the developer tool console and also when I try to print it the console": how exactly do you expect to do these? E.g. do you use the React Developer Tools browser extension? What and where is your code for logging?
